# C++ - Show global variables in debug

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, mingw

When I try to debug, it displays std elements properly, however global variables, stl elements etc. don't display in watches. Whenever I go from function to function, the variables aren't showing up. Is there a way for GDB to automatically display values of global variables and stl elements?

Don't include anything against global variables. I have read on the topic, I'm asking another question.

OS: Windows 7
IDE: Eclipse Luna
Compiler: MinGW
Debugger: GDB-Python27

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, gdb can show the values of any variable while you step.  Use the `display` command:

```
(gdb) display some_global_variable
```

A displayed variable (or expression) will be printed whenever your program stops.  So, for example, after each `next` command.

However, I suspect you are really asking about displaying some global variables in your IDE.  That isn't a gdb question at all, but rather one about the GUI.  gdb does provide all the machinery that a debugger GUI would need to display variables in this same way, however.

Comment: Yes, I was asking about Eclipse. Okay then, I guess I'll create another post. Thanks!